# Помогите написать запрос в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

У меня две таблицы. Категорий и продукты. Связаны они по category_id. Мой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `categories`, `products` WHERE 
price BETWEEN '10' AND '20' 
AND  JOIN title like 'Закуски'
```

Таблица Категорий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица Продуктов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ещё укажите во WHERE, что "Связаны они по category_id". И проверку на точное совпадение выполняют не LIKE, а тупо оператором сравнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` `p`
LEFT JOIN `categories` `c` on `c`.id = `p`.category_id
WHERE `p`.price BETWEEN '10' AND '20' AND `c`.title = 'Закуски';
```

Но на было бы лучше если бы показали структуру таблиц.

Comment: В принципе запрос правильный но я хотел сделать фильтрацию. Тоесть выбор чекбоксом. К примеру выбрать категорию Закуски и Канапе и цена от 5 до 10

Comment: Вы задали вопрос - я дал ответ, для фильтрации выносите в переменные значения и фильтруйте.